# How to change chrome toolbar color dynamically through chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app, google-chrome-theme

Is it possible in chrome extension to dynamically change the color of the browser **toolbar, frames** and **bookmark** text? If yes, how?

Comment: Not in Chrome. Firefox will probably have a [Theming API](https://github.com/nt1m/WebExtensions-Theming-API/blob/master/Proposal.md).

Comment: Closing as duplicate of an old question, but the answer is unfortunately still the same.